# Cannot delete .crdownload files

Tags: gnome, chromium

I recently downloaded pictures from chromium on my desktop and it left the .crdownload files. I have tried moving them to trash and I get the error

```
Error when getting information for file '/home/michael/Desktop/okgo.jpg.crdownload': No such file or directory
```

I have also tried using to terminal to delete them and the command goes through but the icon still remains on my desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have experienced some kind of graphics glitch. Press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to refresh the icons on the desktop screen.

Another thing to check is to go to *Systems Settings* -> *Appearance* -> *Look* tab and change the desktop wallpaper picture back and forth or the .crdownload files may be gone the next time that you reboot the computer.

To change the wallpaper in 18.04 go to *Settings* -> *Background* -> *Wallpapers* tab -> click a background image to select it -> press the *Select* button.

To change the wallpaper in 20.04 go to *Settings* -> *Background* ->  click a background image to select it.

Comment: F5 will do the job as well.

Comment: Korosh's comment about F5, above, is spot on. Wish I'd know about that sooner...

Answer (score 19):

After a downloading has finished, it should be deleted auto but sometimes Desktop (or Nemo, Nautilus etc.) need a refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>), then it will disappear.

Comment: This is indeed the case with these. It's not that nemo can't delete the file, the file is literally not there. And since Chrome has deleted the files from under nemo, nemo had no clue not to remove the desktop representation of them. F5 worked like a charm. 

Perhaps someone should inform the chromium project that they need to send a refresh request via system signal upon removing these files. (if that's even a thing)

Comment: This solve it for me, ubuntu 18.04 with unity

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried both f5 and changing the wallpaper criteria with no success.  To spare yourself too much headache, just restart your computer and all the files must be gone. This is also helpful in refreshing your entire system.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both refreshing the desktop by pressing f5 and changing the wallpaper but with no success.So here is my solution restart your pc and never download any file in desktop always use Document,Download or Picture to save your file
NB: this problem don't appear until i have switch to ubuntu 20LTS